# Associate existing object to futur user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, associations

I m trying to find a method to assocatie lot of objects automatically to multiple user. I have more than 6000 lines (records) object in my DB call "camping". I collect data form different source.

I have one devise user model call "proprietaire" and I want allow user who possede camping to modify his object only. To allow this my first solution was an "proprietaire_id" and "camping_id".

But if want to allow proprietaire to modify his camping i must allow this manualy and this is a long work...

So I find a new thing : I have two same field => Email. Camping email contact can be the same from proprietaire. If email proprietaire is the same to email camping, proprietaire can edit his camping.

I m not sure that the best way because if a proprietaire use another or modify his email he can't edit his camping...

Maybe a "mid" solution can be to save a proprietaire_id if email is the same for proprietaire and camping. But i m not sure too.

Campings_controller.rb

```
before_action :set_camping, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :proprio_owner]
  before_action :authenticate_proprietaire!,except:[:homesearch, :index, :result, :show, :resultnohome]
  before_action :proprio_owner, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

    #Autoriser le proprietaire à modifier son camping s'il a le proprietaire_id
  def proprio_owner
    unless  @camping.proprietaire_id == current_proprietaire.id || @camping.courriel == current_proprietaire.email
      flash[:notice] = "Vous n'êtes pas autorisé à modifier ce camping"
      redirect_to campings_path
    end
  end
```

camping.rb

```
class Camping < ApplicationRecord
belong_to :proprietaire
end
```

proprietaire.rb

```
class Proprietaire < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :campings
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { small: "30x30>", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.jpg"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"] 

         def index

         end
end
```

So do you have a better idea to do that ?
Thanks :)

Comment: Definitely the best solution in the short and long term is to have a `proprietaire_id` in the campings table

Comment: I have proprietaire_id but i need to associate this manually?

Comment: You said that you have the user email in both camping and proprietaire, so you can write a script to associate the existing entries

Comment: I write an if like my example. But i don't know how to save proprietaire_id in my table if email is same on camping and proprietaire table...

Comment: It should be something like


```Camping.all.each do |camping|;
  proprietaire = Proprietaire.find_by(email: camping.email);
  camping.update_attribute :proprietaire_id, proprietaire.id;
end
```